# an error about heap corrupting

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

I wrote a C++ program, actually it's a game.
I've received this error:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in bla bla...

Can someone help me?
That's code, but error occur on line AAA:

```
void r_motions(char **map,int size)
{
    int parameter_i,parameter_j,player_i,player_j;
    int *r_location_i = new int[1],*r_location_j = new int[1];
    player_finder(map,size,player_i,player_j);
    int r_num = robots_finder(map,size,r_location_i,r_location_j);
    for(int i=1;i<=r_num;i++)
    {
        parameter_i =0;
        parameter_j =0;
        if(r_location_i[i]>player_i) parameter_i = -1;
        if(r_location_i[i]<player_i) parameter_i =  1;
        if(r_location_j[i]>player_j) parameter_j = -1;
        if(r_location_j[i]<player_j) parameter_j =  1;
        map[r_location_i[i]][r_location_j[i]] = '.';
        r_location_i[i] = r_location_i[i]+parameter_i;
        r_location_j[i] = r_location_j[i]+parameter_j;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=r_num;i++)
    {
        switch (map[r_location_i[i]][r_location_j[i]])
        {
        case '.': 
            map[r_location_i[i]][r_location_j[i]] = '+';
            break;
        case '@': 
            map[r_location_i[i]][r_location_j[i]] = '+';
            print_map(map,size);
            cout << "Robots win ." << endl;
            sleep(1000);
            exit(1);
            break;
        case '+':
            map[r_location_i[i]][r_location_j[i]] = '*';
            break;
        case '*': 
            map[r_location_i[i]][r_location_j[i]] = '*';
            break;
        default: cout << "what r u doin' ??";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're not going to show us the full error, or tell us which line it actually occurred on, and you haven't tried simplifying your code to figure out which feature causes the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that `map` points to a valid array? At a glance I'd say you're doing some scary things with pointers, and should probably wrap them in classes for safety, and/or use the STL containers.

Answer (score 3):

All right, just for starters, look at this:

```
int *r_location_i = new int[1], ...;
...
for(int i=1;i<=r_num;i++)
  {
    parameter_i =0;
    ...
    if(r_location_i[i]>player_i) parameter_i = -1; // reading outside the array
    ...
    r_location_i[i] = r_location_i[i]+parameter_i; // writing outside the array
    ...
  }
```

Go back and study arrays. **Do not touch another pointer** until you know exactly what's wrong with the code above.